# CakePHP 1.3 Fallback Translation

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization, translation

Using Translate Bahavior on CakePHP 1.3 with no records in the `i18n` table will get non of the content displayed, no matter that there is untranslated record in the main table.

I have found someone that has patched the translate behavior to get the data from the main table if no record in `i18n` but the [first one](http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2010/01/25/cakephp-how-to-fallback-to-default-language-while-using-translate-behavior/) does not apply to CakePHP 1.3
and can't find the second one which site is offline:

`http://codaset.com/robwilkerson/scratchpad/source/master/blob/cakephp/behaviors/translatable.php`

How to get the record from main table as fallback if no `i18n` record is found?

Answer (score 2):

How exactly are you applying i18n? If you just use the `__()` wrapper, it should return whatever is inside if it can't find a translation. Like it says in the [book](https://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Internationalization-Localization.html#internationalizing-your-application):

> The __() function will translate the passed string **if a translation is available**, or return it unmodified.

So if you'd put these kind of strings in your view:

```
<?php __('My untranslated string.'); ?>
```

It should work out just fine, it always works for me this way.